# Hibernate trying to insert into Table that doesn't even exist in Java web application

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, h2, dao

Hi I'm trying to develop a web application and am using an h2 Database. Right now I'm working on a class that's supposed to save "bewerteteAbgaben" in my table "BEWERTETEABGABEN"

This is the bean for adding the "bewerteteAbgabe":

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
@FacesConfig
public class BewertungAddBean implements Serializable {
    /**
     * Abgabenspeicher
     */
    @Inject
    private BewerteteAbgabeDAO bewerteteAbgabeDAO;

    /**
     * Aufgabenspeicher
     */
    @Inject
    private BewerteteAufgabeDAO bewerteteAufgabeDAO;

    /**
     * Umleitung
     */
    @Inject
    private ExternalContext externalContext;

    @Getter
    private TreeNode root;

    @Getter
    private  Abgabe abgabe;

    @Inject
    private AbgabeDAO abgabeDAO;

    @Getter
    private BewerteteAbgabe bewerteteAbgabe;

    @Getter
    private static List<Student> teilnehmer = new ArrayList<>();

    @Inject
    private StudentDAO studentDAO;

    @Getter
    private Student student;

    /**
     * Initialisiert diese Bean.
     */
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        Map<String, String> parameterMap = externalContext.getRequestParameterMap();
        String email = parameterMap.get("email");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(parameterMap.get("ID"));
        student = studentDAO.findByEmail(email).orElse(null);
        abgabe = abgabeDAO.findById(id).orElse(null);
        teilnehmer.add(student);
        buildBewertungsbaum();
    }

    public void add() throws IOException {
        List<TreeNode> children = root.getChildren();
        BewerteteAufgabe bewerteteAufgabe;
        for (TreeNode child : children) {
            bewerteteAufgabe = (BewerteteAufgabe) child.getData();
            bewerteteAufgabeDAO.insert(bewerteteAufgabe);
        }
        bewerteteAbgabeDAO.insert(bewerteteAbgabe);
        externalContext.redirect("bewertung.xhtml");

    }

    private void buildBewertungsbaum() {
        bewerteteAbgabe = new BewerteteAbgabe(abgabe, teilnehmer, null);
        root = new DefaultTreeNode(bewerteteAbgabe, null);
        for (Aufgabe aufgabe : abgabe.getAufgaben()) {
            if (aufgabe.getTeilAufgaben().isEmpty()) {
                BewerteteAufgabe bewAufgabe = new BewerteteAufgabe(aufgabe, 0, null);
                TreeNode node = new DefaultTreeNode(bewAufgabe, root);
            } else
                createBewertungsNode(aufgabe);
        }
    }

    private void createBewertungsNode(Aufgabe aufgabe) {
        for (Aufgabe teilaufgabe : aufgabe.getTeilAufgaben()) {
            if (teilaufgabe.getTeilAufgaben().isEmpty()) {
                BewerteteAufgabe bewAufgabe = new BewerteteAufgabe(teilaufgabe, 0, null);
                TreeNode node = new DefaultTreeNode(bewAufgabe, root);
            } else
                createBewertungsNode(teilaufgabe);
        }
    }

    public static String studentenToString() {
        StringBuilder names = new StringBuilder();
        for (Student student : teilnehmer) {
            names.append(student.getVorname()).append(" ").append(student.getNachname());
            if (teilnehmer.size() > 1 && student != teilnehmer.get(teilnehmer.size() - 1))
                names.append(", ");
        }
        return names.toString();
    }

}
```

This is the BewerteteAbgabe class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BEWERTETEABGABE")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BewerteteAbgabe {
    /**
     * ID einer bewerteten Abgabe
     */
    @Id
    @NonNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int ID;

    /**
     * Abgabe, die bewertet wird
     */
    @JoinColumn(name = "ABGABE")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private Abgabe abgabe;

    /**
     * Studenten, fuer die die Abgabe bewertet wird
     */
    @Setter
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<Student> studenten;

    /**
     * Tutoren, die bewerten
     */
    @Setter
    @Transient //TODO: Hier muss eine neue Tabelle eingefügt werden.
    private List<User> tutoren;

    /**
     * Kommentar zur Bewertung
     */
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NotBlank
    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "KOMMENTAR")
    private String kommentar;

    /**
     * Abgabenresultat eines Studenten
     */
    @Getter
    @Setter
    //@Column(name = "RESULTAT")
    @Transient //TODO: Neue Resultat-Tabelle joinen
    private ZwischenBewertung.Resultat resultat;

    /**
     * Map zwischen der Aufgabe und ihrer Bewertung
     */
    @Transient //TODO: Hier muss eine neue Tabelle eingefügt werden.
    private Map<Aufgabe, BewerteteAufgabe> bewertung = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * Konstruktor
     *
     * @param abgabe    Zu bewertende Abgabe
     * @param studenten Student, zu welchem Abgabe gehoert
     * @param kommentar Kommentar zur Abgabe
     */
    public BewerteteAbgabe(Abgabe abgabe, List<Student> studenten, String kommentar) {
        this.abgabe = abgabe;
        this.studenten = studenten;
        this.kommentar = kommentar;
    }

    public BewerteteAbgabe(Abgabe abgabe, List<Student> studenten) {
        this.abgabe = abgabe;
        this.studenten = studenten;
    }

    /**
     * gibt Tutoren zurueck, die Aufgabe korrigiert haben
     *
     * @return Tutoren, die korrigiert haben
     */
    public List<User> getTutoren() {
        return new ArrayList<>(this.tutoren);
    }

    /**
     * gibt Studenten zurueck, die Abgabe gemacht haben
     *
     * @return Studenten der Abgabe
     */
    public List<Student> getStudenten() {
        return new ArrayList<>(this.studenten);
    }

    /**
     * Fuegt die Bewertung zur Aufgabe hinzu.
     *
     * @param bewerteteAufgabe, die Bewertung
     * @throws NullPointerException     BewerteteAufgabe ist null
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException wenn die {@link Aufgabe} nicht in der {@link Abgabe} vorhanden ist.
     */
    public void addBewerteteAufgabe(BewerteteAufgabe bewerteteAufgabe) {

        Objects.requireNonNull(bewerteteAufgabe);

        if (!abgabe.containsAufgabe(bewerteteAufgabe.getAufgabe()))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(MessageFormat.format("Die ubergebene Aufgabe {0} ist nicht in der Abgabe {1} enthalten.", abgabe.getAufgaben(), abgabe));

        bewertung.put(bewerteteAufgabe.getAufgabe(), bewerteteAufgabe);
    }

    /**
     * entfernt Bewertung einer Aufgabe
     *
     * @param bewerteteAufgabe bewerteteAufgabe, die entfernt werden soll
     * @return Erfolg
     * @throws NullPointerException     BewerteteAufgabe ist null
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException Aufgabe ist nicht in Bewertung
     */

    public boolean removeBewerteteAufgabe(BewerteteAufgabe bewerteteAufgabe) {
        if (bewerteteAufgabe == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("bewerteteAufgabe ist null");
        }
        if (!(bewertung.containsKey(bewerteteAufgabe.getAufgabe()))) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Aufgabe ist nicht in Bewertung");
        }
        return this.bewertung.remove(bewerteteAufgabe.getAufgabe(), bewerteteAufgabe);
    }

    /**
     * @param aufgabe Aufgabe, auf dessen Bewertung wir zugreifen wollen
     * @return Bewertung der Aufgabe
     * @throws NullPointerException     Aufgabe ist null
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException Aufgabe ist nicht in Abgabe
     */
    public BewerteteAufgabe getBewerteteAufgabe(Aufgabe aufgabe) {

        Objects.requireNonNull(aufgabe);

        if (!abgabe.containsAufgabe(aufgabe))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(MessageFormat.format("Die ubergebene Aufgabe {0} ist nicht in der Abgabe {1} enthalten.", aufgabe, abgabe));

        return bewertung.get(aufgabe);
    }

    /**
     * berechnet Gesamtnote der Abgabe
     *
     * @return Gesamtnote
     */
    public ZwischenBewertung erstelleZwischenBewertung() {

        ErreichtePunkteAufgabenConsumer erreichtePunkteAufgabenConsumer = new ErreichtePunkteAufgabenConsumer(this);

        for (Aufgabe hauptAufgabe : abgabe.getAufgaben())
            hauptAufgabe.walkRecursiv(erreichtePunkteAufgabenConsumer);

        return new ZwischenBewertung(abgabe, erreichtePunkteAufgabenConsumer.summePunkte);
    }

    /**
     * Consumer, der ausrechnet wie viele Punkte gewichtet in einer Aufgabe erreicht wurden
     */
    private static class ErreichtePunkteAufgabenConsumer implements Consumer<Aufgabe> {

        /**
         * Gewichtete erreichte Punkte
         */
        public float summePunkte;

        /**
         * bewertete Abgabe fuer die Punkte summiert werden
         */
        private final BewerteteAbgabe bewerteteAbgabe;

        /**
         * Konstruktor
         *
         * @param bewerteteAbgabe beweretete Abgabe
         */
        public ErreichtePunkteAufgabenConsumer(BewerteteAbgabe bewerteteAbgabe) {
            this.bewerteteAbgabe = bewerteteAbgabe;
        }

        /**
         * Summiert die gewichteten Punkte fuer bewertete Aufgaben
         *
         * @param aufgabe Aufgabe, dessen erreichte Punkte summiert werden
         */
        @Override
        public void accept(Aufgabe aufgabe) {

            BewerteteAufgabe bewerteteAufgabe = bewerteteAbgabe.getBewerteteAufgabe(aufgabe);

            if (bewerteteAufgabe != null)
                summePunkte += bewerteteAufgabe.getErreichtePunkte() * aufgabe.getGewichtKumuliert();
        }
    }

}
```

This is the DAO:

```
@Singleton
public class BewerteteAbgabeDAOImpl implements BewerteteAbgabeDAO {
    @Override
    public void insert(BewerteteAbgabe bewerteteAbgabe) throws NullPointerException {
        HibernateUtil.execute(s -> s.save(bewerteteAbgabe));
    }

    @Override
    public void update(BewerteteAbgabe bewerteteAbgabe) throws NullPointerException {
        HibernateUtil.execute(s -> s.update(bewerteteAbgabe));
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(BewerteteAbgabe bewerteteAbgabe) {
        HibernateUtil.execute(s -> s.delete(bewerteteAbgabe));
    }

    @Override
    public List<BewerteteAbgabe> alleBewerteteAbgaben() {
        return HibernateUtil.find(s -> s.createQuery("from BewerteteAbgabe ", BewerteteAbgabe.class).list());
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<BewerteteAbgabe> findById(int id) {
        return HibernateUtil.find(s -> Optional.ofNullable(s.get(BewerteteAbgabe.class, id)));
    }
}
```

And this is the SQL for the Table I'm saving them in:

```
CREATE TABLE `BewerteteAbgabe` (
                                   `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                   `abgabe` INT NOT NULL,
                                   `kommentar` varchar(255),
                                   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Now, when I try to add the "bewerteteAbgabe" I get this message:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "BEWERTETEABGABE_STUDENT" not found; SQL statement:
insert into BEWERTETEABGABE_STUDENT (BewerteteAbgabe_ID, studenten_EMAIL) values (?, ?) [42102-200]
```

and this is a table that does not even exist.
Any help would be welcome because I've been trying to fix this issue for hours

Answer (score 1):

You have a defined a many to many relation between your `BewerteteAbgabe` class and your `Student` class.

```java
@Setter
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<Student> studenten;
```

Hibernate tries to model that relationship with a relation table, that contains an entry for each pair of student and test.
That table is automatically named after the two objects it connects.

Try it and create the table and save some `BewerteteAbgabe` with students in it. You will see the connection between your classes inside that table.

Have a look at https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many. There is a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have added the table and when I save a bewerteteAbgabe another abgabe is being saved, do you perhaps know why this is?

Comment: You have a field `Abgabe abgabe` with a `@ManyToOne` and a `@JoinColumn` annotation. When you save a BewerteteAbgabe wich contains a Abgabe, the Abgabe is also saved. The reason is the `CascadeType.ALL`. All operations to the parent object are propagated to the child objects.